# SQL query for fetching record from a table it's taking a long time but works as expected when i run exec sp_updatestats

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, database-administration

I have a table in SQL Server 2014 which has ~ 3 lk data  and transaction per day is 3k.

I wrote a query to fetch the data from another table which has a non-cluster index by applying filter with 4 column. It works as expected for 7-10 days, and suddenly it takes long time to retrieve the data.

At this situation if I fire `exec sp_updatestats` it will respond as expected.

Now my questions are:

1. If I run the `exec sp_updatestats`, will it impact my existing transaction which is ongoing in the DB ?
2. What is the disadvantage of using this `exec sp_updatestats` ?
3. Is there any alternative of `exec sp_updatestats` ?

Answer (score -1):

Ad 1. Your transaction (in the strict sense) will continue. Updating statistics can (and typically will) cause recompilation.

Ad 2. That it updates all statistics (that have been automatically created by SQL Server). So it can effect the next run of any query, because of recompilation

Ad 3. In your case it might be sufficient to run UPDATE STATISTICS for your table. You could also consider running it during off hours, e.g. every night.